# NextJs, React, passing data through two components

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-props

I have a variable in my child component that holds the data of its height.  I need to pass it through its parent and into the parent's parent.  I am able to pass it to the parent, but don't understand why passing it to the parent's parent isn't working.  The error I am getting is:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: props.func is not a function

Source
components\layout.js (22:10) @ Object.pull_data [as func]

  20 |  const navHeight = data;
  21 |   console.log(navHeight); 
> 22 |   props.func(navHeight);

  24 | }
```

**Child component:**

```
export default function Navbarmain(props) {

  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    const navHeight = ref.current?.clientHeight;
    props.func(navHeight);
  }, []);


  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
```

**Child's parent:**

```
export default function Layout({ children, home }, props) {

  const pull_data = (data) => {

   const navHeight = data;
    console.log(navHeight); // Correctly outputs Height of child component
    props.func(navHeight);  // Attempt to do a repeat of what I just did

  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.layoutWrap}>
      <Navbarmain func={pull_data}></Navbarmain>
```

**Parent's parent:**

```
export default function Home({ allPostsData }) {
      const pull_data = (data) => {
    
        const navHeight = data;
         console.log(navHeight); 
    
       }
     
    
    
      return (
        <div>
          <Layout home func={pull_data}>
```

Comment: Why are you passing a function around in props rather than just passing your variable?

Comment: Not sure, how do I do that?  Just picked up react this week

Comment: You're trying to use 2 parameters in `Layout`, which is wrong. The first parameter is `props`, if you want to use `children, home` and the rest should be called `props` you should do the following: `{children, home, ...props}` and then use it as `props.func(navHeight)` or destructure also the `func` as: `{children, home, func}` and then do `func(navHeight)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in the `Child's parent'` s component props. You are mixing props inside curly braces with `props` `({ children, home }, props)`. If you refactor in this way it will work without problem

https://codesandbox.io/embed/fervent-cohen-td6sig?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
export default function Layout({ children, home, func }) {

  const pull_data = (data) => {

   const navHeight = data;
    console.log(navHeight); // Correctly outputs Height of child component
    func(navHeight);  // Attempt to do a repeat of what I just did

  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.layoutWrap}>
      <Navbarmain func={pull_data}></Navbarmain>
```